# Rails carrierwave upload image without skewing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, minimagick

Is it possible to upload picture to have it sit nicely in the middle without being skewed? I don't want user to crop the image.

avatar_uploader.rb

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  if Rails.env.production?
    storage :fog
  else
    storage :file
  end

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fill => [100, 100]
  end
   end
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end    
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use resize_and_pad instead of resize_to_fill. Documentation is at http://carrierwave.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/CarrierWave/RMagick.html#M000066